# Hyper-V "Generic Failure"

Tags: hyper-v

[The error code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iIoN.png)I'm getting "*Generic Failure*" error when doing "*Quick Create*" and when I try to access the virtual switch in Windows 10 Hyper-V. Anyone have any suggestions? I've tried turning Programs features on and off, I've tried uninstalling the virtual switches, updates- I've probably did almost everything already.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone has any suggestions?

You most likely do not have the `Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch` installed.  If that is the case, you will have to install it, and then perform a reboot.

> [image]

Source: [Hyper-V error when creating a virtual switch](https://www.tenforums.com/virtualization/10699-hyper-v-error-when-creating-virtual-switch.html)

Comment: You click on **Protocol** and hit **Add**, if you have your own question, submit your own question with more details other than “I have this problem” be as specific as possible.  Please use this comment section exclusively for feedback about the answer.  Any commentary that isn’t feedback about the answer will be reported as “no longer needed”